# Calculating landcover proportion for polygon on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to calculate the area of six landcover classes within a polygon. However the proportions I get back do not add up to one. For example:

```
var CL = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NASS/CDL').select('cropland') //crop data layer for USA
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2009-01-01', '2009-12-31')); //example year

var area = ee.Image.pixelArea(); 


// I am reclassifying all images to six basic categories
// 1 - corn
// 2 - cotton
// 3 - soybeans
// 4 - other crop
// 5 - native vegetation (loosely defined)
// 6 - non habitat

var propNames = ee.List(['from', 'to']);
var fromToList = ee.List(
  fromToFc.reduceColumns({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.toList().repeat(propNames.size()),
    selectors: propNames
  })
  .get('list')
);

var from = fromToList.get(0);
var to = fromToList.get(1);

var remapping = function(image) {
  return image.remap(from, to, null, 'cropland');
};

var CL2 = CL.map(remapping);

print('CL2',CL2);




var buffed = geometry.buffer(2500);

var geom_area = buffed.area();
var fcomp = CL2.filterBounds(buffed);
print("fcomp",fcomp)

var fcomp_corn = fcomp.first()
  .mask(fcomp.first().eq(1))
  .multiply(area)
  .divide(geom_area)
  .select([0],['corn']);

var fcomp_cotton = fcomp.first()
  .mask(fcomp.first().eq(2))
  .multiply(area)
  .divide(geom_area)
  .select([0],['cotton']);
  
var fcomp_soy = fcomp.first()
  .mask(fcomp.first().eq(3))
  .multiply(area)
  .divide(geom_area)
  .select([0],['soy']);
  
var fcomp_other = fcomp.first()
  .mask(fcomp.first().eq(4))
  .multiply(area)
  .divide(geom_area)
  .select([0],['other']);
  
var fcomp_native = fcomp.first()
  .mask(fcomp.first().eq(5))
  .multiply(area)
  .divide(geom_area)
  .select([0],['native']);
  
var fcomp_nonhabit = fcomp.first()
  .mask(fcomp.first().eq(6))
  .multiply(area)
  .divide(geom_area)
  .select([0],['nonhabit']);
  


Map.addLayer(fcomp_native.clip(buffed),{},"native");
Map.addLayer(fcomp_nonhabit.clip(buffed),{},"non-habitat");
Map.centerObject(fcomp_nonhabit.clip(buffed));

var area_image = fcomp_corn.addBands(fcomp_cotton)
.addBands(fcomp_soy)
.addBands(fcomp_other)
.addBands(fcomp_native)
.addBands(fcomp_nonhabit);

var areas = area_image.reduceRegion({
reducer:ee.Reducer.sum(),
geometry: buffed,
scale: 30,
maxPixels:1e13
});

print("geometry area",geom_area);

print("areas",areas);
```

gives me the following proportions

| Landcover | proportion |
| --- | --- |
| corn | 0.0278 |
| cotton | 0.0000 |
| native | 0.6739 |
| nonhabitat | 5.1639 |
| other | 0.0039 |
| soy | 0.0025 |

Obviously, 'nonhabitat' is wrong here. Does anyone know what is going wrong in my code?

here is the GEE link:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/9380d97e4489f43f20787bc79bdc53c2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a simpler approach for calculating areas based in your **fcomp** image. Code snippet looks as follows and complete code is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/83dde965ee8862e4ff418f422cfcf82d).

```
var fcomp2 = fcomp.first();

var area_image2 = fcomp2
  .rename('area_image2');

//print("area_image2", area_image2);

var mergedAllFunction = function(image) {

 var thres1 = area_image2.eq(1).rename('corn');
 var thres2 = area_image2.eq(2).rename('cotton');
 var thres3 = area_image2.eq(3).rename('soy');
 var thres4 = area_image2.eq(4).rename('other');
 var thres5 = area_image2.eq(5).rename('native');
 var thres6 = area_image2.eq(6).rename('nonhabit');

 return image.addBands(area_image2).addBands([thres1, thres2, thres3, thres4, thres5, thres6]);
};

var median = CL.median();

var merged = mergedAllFunction(median);

//print("merged", merged);

var areas_c = merged
    .select(['corn', 'cotton', 'soy', 'other', 'native', 'nonhabit'])
    .multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
      geometry: buffed,  // a geometry
      scale: 30,   
      maxPixels: 1e9  
    });

print("complete areas in square meters", areas_c); //complete areas in square meters

print("areas sum", ee.List(areas_c.values()).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()));

var areas_p = merged
    .select(['corn', 'cotton', 'soy', 'other', 'native', 'nonhabit'])
    .multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(geom_area))
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
      geometry: buffed,  // a geometry
      scale: 30,   
      maxPixels: 1e9  
    });

print("areas as proportion", areas_p); //areas as proportion

print("proportion areas sum", ee.List(areas_p.values()).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()));
```

After running above code in GEE code editor, I got results of following image. It can be observed that sum areas is comparable with geometry area and the sum of obtained area proportions is 1; as expected (relative errors are very low in both cases).

[image]